# Why input data not getting added to firebase firestore collection

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, chat

I am building a chat application using firebase and react. The problem facing is that the input data is not getting added to the firebase firestore collection. The collection is named messages.
The output is like the input is getting displayed and disappeared as it is not saved in the database.
The code is given below:

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import 'firebase/firestore';
import 'firebase/auth';
import 'firebase/analytics';

import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import { useCollectionData } from 'react-firebase-hooks/firestore';

firebase.initializeApp({
  //firebase_credentials
})

const auth = firebase.auth();
const firestore = firebase.firestore();


function App() {

  const [user] = useAuthState(auth);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header>
        <h1>SuperChat </h1>
        <SignOut />
      </header>

      <section>
        {user ? <ChatRoom /> : <SignIn />}
      </section>

    </div>
  );
}

function SignIn() {

  const signInWithGoogle = () => {
    const provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button className="sign-in" onClick={signInWithGoogle}>Sign in with Google</button>
      <p>Don't wait, messages are gonna disappear in a while</p>
    </>
  )

}

function SignOut() {
  return auth.currentUser && (
    <button className="sign-out" onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>Sign Out</button>
  )
}


function ChatRoom() {
  const dummy = useRef();
  const messagesRef = firestore.collection('messages');
  const query = messagesRef.orderBy('createdAt').limit(25);

  const [messages] = useCollectionData(query, { idField: 'id' });

  const [formValue, setFormValue] = useState('');


  const sendMessage = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const { uid, photoURL } = auth.currentUser;

    await messagesRef.add({
      text: formValue,
      createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
      uid,
      photoURL
    })

    setFormValue('');
    dummy.current.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth' });
  }

  return (<>
    <main>

      {messages && messages.map(msg => <ChatMessage key={msg.id} message={msg} />)}

      <span ref={dummy}></span>

    </main>

    <form onSubmit={sendMessage}>

      <input value={formValue} onChange={(e) => setFormValue(e.target.value)} placeholder="say something nice" />

      <button type="submit" disabled={!formValue}>send</button>

    </form>
  </>)
}


function ChatMessage(props) {
  const { text, uid, photoURL } = props.message;

  const messageClass = uid === auth.currentUser.uid ? 'sent' : 'received';

  return (<>
    <div className={`message ${messageClass}`}>
      <img src={photoURL || 'https://feedback.seekingalpha.com/s/cache/ff/f2/fff2493e0063ac43f7161be10e0d7fff.png'} />
      <p>{text}</p>
    </div>
  </>)
}


export default App
```

Comment: I think you should catch errors of your "await messagesRef.add()" operation. I suspect the lines below "createdAt: firebase.fire..." are the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are not properly setting the object to be added as a document in Firestore in the `messagesRef.add()` method. If you check this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) you can see that the `add()` method should have a structure like:

```
db.collection("collectionName").add({
    field1: "someValue1",
    field2: "someValue2",
    ...
    fieldN: "someValueN"
})
```

So what you should do in your code is the following:

```
await messagesRef.add({
  text: formValue,
  createdAt: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
  photoURL : "someURLvalue"
})
```

**NOTE**: I took out the uid from the example above because using `add()` the ID is automatically generated.